# C# SortedSet.Max Time Complexity

Tags: c#, time-complexity, sortedset

What is the time complexity of `SortedSet.Max` or `SortedSet.Min` properties in C#?

Comment: The majority of the cost will be this line of code. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedset.cs,235

Comment: I think you're going to have to specify the .NET version. The implementation seems to be different between .NET Framework ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedset.cs,226)) and .NET Core / .NET 5.0 ([source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs,1530)).

Comment: Thanks to you both! I just checked your links and it turned out the time complexity is Log(n).

Comment: I am able to pass this leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/minimize-deviation-in-array/submissions/ using sortedSet.Max property. When I was using sortedSet.Last() I was getting Time Limit Exceeded. Seems to be performant to a certain degree. I wish the MS documentation would mention the Big O complexity of the sorted set Max property. This means its probably comparable to popping a Min from a priority queue heap. My guess is Log N in .NET 6 but don't quote me.

Answer (score 0):

O(log n) because use this method:

```
public T? Max => this.MaxInternal;

internal virtual T? MaxInternal
{
  get
  {
    if (this.root == null)
      return default (T);
    SortedSet<T>.Node node = this.root;
    while (node.Right != null)
      node = node.Right;
    return node.Item;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).